# Eclipse won't export as a JAR

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, export

I realize similar questions have been asked, but mine seems to be unique. When I attempt to export my project as a JAR the project itself does not appear in the export window. Can anyone help me?

Also, I'm not sure if this changes anything, but I used a Java Decompiler to decompile the source, put it in a folder, and created a project with the same name as said folder to be able to edit it. As well I have asked the devs of the  JAR and they said it was fine.

Answer (score 1):

Does the project have an output folder?  Is it an actual Java project that is compiling?  Take a look at the build path and see if anything is funky.

Comment: You're missing the tell-tale "J" in the project icon that indicates it's a Java Project, which is the kind of project it expects to export as a .jar file.  Without it being a real Java Project, it doesn't know what's source and where the correct root of your output is.